# cassandra-stress what does it mean?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-stress

I ran cassandra-stress on an ec2 m3-medium which hosts 1 of 3 nodes in my cluster.

`cassandra-stress write n=100000  -schema "replication(strategy=NetworkTopologyStrategy, us-east=1)"`

I got this result

Results:

op rate                   : 2794 [WRITE:2794]

partition rate            : 2794 [WRITE:2794]

row rate                  : 2794 [WRITE:2794]
...
Total operation time      : 00:00:35

apart from the other results that come.

I want to know is this correct for a m3-medium system?

Also i want to know does this mean i can only do around 2794 writes per second successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Check below is the description of all the output metrics for cassandra-stress. Those metrics seems to be quiet fair for a m3-medium system

[image]

Comment: i ran the cassandra-stress simultaneously on 2 out 3 nodes each gave op/s as around 2200 does it mean total is actually 4400 op/s ?

Comment: Yes it is 2200 /sec per node